Dynamically update the options for a Swagger parameter
I'm working with Swashbuckle to generate Swagger document to my API built with .NET 8. I came into a situation where I have a route with 2 parameters:
{param1}/{param2}

param1 is of type Enum and param2 is a string that get different values according to the value of param1.
For example, if the Enum options for param1 are x, y, z, for x the allowed values of param2 are 1, 2, 3, for y the allowed values are 4, 5, 6 and for z the allowed values are 7, 8, 9.
In the generated Swagger document I get a drop down list with the values x, y, z for param1 and I want to have the same drop down list for param2 that will be changed according to the selected value of param1 and will contain the allowed values for each value of param1. I couldn't find any out-of-the-box way to do it, so I was wondering if it's even possible?

In your requirment, we are trying to convert the string input to become a select dropdown, and the options for the string parameter shall be changed based on the select option in the first dropdown selection which is for the first enum parameter. I'm afraid this is impossible without creating custom swagger UI. Here's a case relatd to create custom swagger UI. Then you might have something similar to codes below in your UI page.
ui.onComplete(function() {
    const param1Element = document.querySelector('[name="param1"]');
    const param2Element = document.querySelector('[name="param2"]');

    param1Element.addEventListener('change', function() {
        const param1Value = param1Element.value;
        let options = [];

        if (param1Value === 'x') {
            options = ['1', '2', '3'];
        } else if (param1Value === 'y') {
            options = ['4', '5', '6'];
        } else if (param1Value === 'z') {
            options = ['7', '8', '9'];
        }

        param2Element.innerHTML = '';
        options.forEach(option => {
            const opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = option;
            opt.innerHTML = option;
            param2Element.appendChild(opt);
        });
    });
});

Just like you can see, only enum values can be set to selection dropdown format in swagger UI, so that it's the same for the second parameter, we can only try to convert the string parameter to enum type, then we can set allowed values for parameter2. But if we want to set dynamic value for it, we need to rewrite the whole swagger UI. I don't think this is a good idea, so that setting all allowed value with 123456789 which could cover all enum for parameter1 shall be a temp workaround which cost the least effort.
This requires us to set enum-to-string convert with builder.Services.AddControllers() .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()); });, then we can get UI like this.

